# comparison of decimal numbers logic in UNIX

Tags: unix

It is not working if it is decimal value comparison. Please debug the code and provide me the solution. Please find the below code
Thanks in Advance..

```
i=2.4524
j=2.430
s=0.2
sub=`echo "$i - $j" | bc`
if (( $sub <= $s ))
then
echo "red"
else
echo "green"
fi
```

Comment: Here're few of the solutions:

[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24721/how-to-compare-to-floating-point-number-in-a-shell-script][1]

[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in][2] 


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24721/how-to-compare-to-floating-point-number-in-a-shell-script
  [2]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in

Answer (score 0):

Try this out I think this will solve your problem

```
    i=2.4524
    j=2.430
    s=0.2
    sub=`echo "$i - $j" | bc`
    if ( $sub le $s )
    then
    echo "red"
    else
    echo "green"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `expr`:

```
i=2.4524
j=2.430
s=0.2
sub=`echo "$i - $j" | bc`
if expr "$sub" '<=' "$s" > /dev/null; then
    echo "red"
else
    echo "green"
fi
```

Using `bc` can also be an option as well but it's less efficient as you have to summon a subshell and that you have to read and compare its output with `1`.

```
if [ "`echo "$sub <= $s" | bc`" = 1 ]; then
    echo "red"
else
    echo "green"
fi
```